# Can you discover for which party US Supreme Court Justices voted?

Tags: united-states, voting

[This](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2008/02/11/AR2008021102753.html) Washington Post article dated Feb 12 2008 reveals some information about past votes of SCOTUS justices, but where can such information be found for other past and current justices?

Comment: There's no requirement that anyone declare what party they vote for. (Some states require that you register under a political party, but that doesn't restrict who you vote for in general elections)

Comment: Are you really asking about how they voted in their function as US citizens in elections like congress or president? These are of course just as secret as your own votes. Or rather about how they voted in their function as justices during supreme court cases? The latter is usually hard to interpret as voting for the position of a specific party.

Answer (score 5):

Justices may be registered as one party or another, and you may be able to find that out through public records or some kind of public announcement from the justice. But that tells you nothing about *who* they actually voted for.